# Is there any difference between those two notations of a quantum state?

Tags: notation

In ["Quantum Computing verstehen"](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-3-8348-2278-9), the author uses both $|ab>$ and $|a,b>$ to describe the state of a 2-bit quantum register. Is there any important difference between those two notations or do they basically mean the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's the same in quantum information theory. They both mean $|a\rangle\otimes|b\rangle$. The second is just a little more explicit than the first since you're separating the two vectors by a comma. In quantum information this isn't so much a problem since $a$ and $b$ only take the values of $0$ or $1$, but in more general contexts (i.e. number states), the comma is imperative because it is difficult to discern the exact meaning of $|ab\rangle$. Take for instance $|231\rangle$ in the former notation in a composite number state system (like two harmonic oscillators combined). How would you interpret this? $|2\rangle\otimes|31\rangle$ or $|23\rangle\otimes|1\rangle$? With a comma in place it becomes clear what is meant and there is no ambiguity.

Answer (score 1):

According to this article [Composite bras and kets](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bra%E2%80%93ket_notation#Composite_bras_and_kets) there is no difference.